# FFMPEG and H264 encode mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, h.264, mp4

I tried to encode a video `mov` to `mp4` width `h264` codec but I get this error :

```
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

But when I check if `h264` if supported by my config I saw it does :

```
DVD h264 H.264 / AVC / MPG-4 AVC/ MPEG-4 part 10
```

and my code :

```
FFMPEG -y -i video.mov -vcodec h264 video.mp4 ;
```

Can someone help me with this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run `ffmpeg -codecs`; it will list all the supported codecs, and make sure you have `libx264` which is the name of the H.264 encoder. The decoder in ffmpeg is named `h264`.

If you are compiling ffmpeg you need to compile and install x264 and then compile ffmpeg using compile options `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264`. See [Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu Hardy Heron](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuideHardy) or [How to quickly compile libx264](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20libx264). Alternatively, you can use an already compiled [static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds).